# How to get active product's cancel subscription in In-App Purchase in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app, in-app-subscription

I've done successfully in-app purchase in my application with following demo: https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ios-swift-in-app-subscription-with-receipt-validation

**Issue:** how to get the current active product which was canceled subscription with receipt data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You get it the same way as they do with `expiration_date` in `getExpirationDateFromResponse()`.

**Note:** The `cancellation_date` field is added to the receipt only when the subscription was canceled by Apple customer support.

**Edit**: How to get `expiration_intent`?

Based on the function `getExpirationDateFromResponse(jsonResponse:)` (from the link in your question) you could access `expiration_intent` like this:

```
guard let unifiedReceipt = jsonResponse["unified_receipt"] as? NSDictionary,
    let pendingRenewalInfos = unifiedReceipt["pending_renewal_info"] as? NSArray,
    let latestInfo = pendingRenewalInfos.firstObject as? NSDictionary,
    let expirationIntent = latestInfo["expiration_intent"] as? String else { fatalError("Couldn‘t determine expiration intent") }
print("expiration_intent \(expirationIntent)")
```

Comment: Is it possible to check `cancellation_date` using a sandbox in the receipt? if yes then please tell me how? @Paul Schröder

Comment: I made an update to my answer, because I made small mistake. To your question: it is not possible to cancel a subscription, because this can only do Apple.

Comment: When a user cancelled his subscription, then the `expiration_intent` in `pending_renewal_info` is set to `1`. This will be set also in the sandbox, after your subscription stops renewing.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to cancel subscription from the user side on the sandbox and how would I get the `expiration_intent` in `pending_renewal_info` using Sandbox.

Comment: Subscriptions in the sandbox renew five times and then stop to renew. After that, your server receives a `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` notification. Which contains the `expiration_intent` (in the sandbox it is always `1`). I have edited my answer to show you how to access the `expiration_intent` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can Access this information from Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalInfo.willAutoRenew at StoreKit2.
WillAutoRenew variable tell us the subscription will renew or not.
Note: I am assuming that you have one Subscription group.

When start any Subscription which has an group, it willAutoRenew variable set up as true. When user cancel the subscription this variable will change as false.

To open below window please fallow this path: XCODE -> Debug -> StoreKit -> Manage Transactions.

[image]

Please Click on Subscription Option button. After Purchased an AutoReNewable subscription transaction will be come here.

[image]

Select Cancel Subscription and then click on Done button.

[image]

As you can see the picture The subscription will not renew after cancelled by user. So You can learn cancelled information with below function. Please give the product which you want information of cancelled or not.

```
func IsWillRenew(product: Product) async -> Bool? {
    guard let SubscriptionGroupStatus = try? await product.subscription?.status.first else {
        print("There is no AutoRenewable Group")
        return nil
    }
    
    guard case .verified(let renewalInfo) = SubscriptionGroupStatus.renewalInfo else {
        print("The App Store could not verify your subscription status.")
        return nil
    }
    
    return renewalInfo.willAutoRenew
}
```

Result

[image]

To get Transaction aka Receipt information you can use below function.

```
@MainActor
func TransactionInformations() async {
    for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
        do {
            //Check whether the transaction is verified. If it isn’t, catch `failedVerification` error.
            let transaction = try checkVerified(result)
            
            switch transaction.productType {
            case .autoRenewable:
                let TransactionInformation = transaction
                print("TransactionInformation", TransactionInformation)
            default: break
            }
        } catch {
            print("Transaction Verify Error: ",error)
        }
    }
}

func checkVerified<T>(_ result: VerificationResult<T>) throws -> T {
    //Check whether the JWS passes StoreKit verification.
    switch result {
    case .unverified:
        //StoreKit parses the JWS, but it fails verification.
        throw StoreError.failedVerification
    case .verified(let safe):
        //The result is verified. Return the unwrapped value.
        return safe
    }
}
```

Result

[image]